# Do Brazil and Panama allow passengers to transit without a transit visa?

Tags: air-travel

I am traveling from Accra, Ghana; to Kingston, Jamaica. Looking for a way to avoid transit visas.

Comment: What's your nationality, Ghanaian? You're travelling by plane, right?
 (guessing from your tag)

Comment: Can you split this into two questions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as "unclear" because transit requirements vary depending on the nationality of the traveler.